# NextJS and React: How can i return pages from server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js

For my Website I use React and NextJS. I have a custom server. My `server.js` looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.post('/', (req, res) => {
            if (req.body.code === 'DE') {
                return server.render(req, res, '/de/', req.query)
            }
        })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
        })
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.error(ex.stack)
        process.exit(1)
  })
```

The function `server.post` is used to check whether the client is from Germany or not. If the client comes from Germany, the `index.js` file should be returned from the directory `/pages/de/`.

On the Client Side i use the `componentDidMount()` Function to detect the country of the Client and send this information to the server:

```js
//located in: /pages/index.js

class Component extends Component {

  
  componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=XXXXXXXXX')
        .then(function (response) {
            const countryCode = response.data.country_code;
            console.log(countryCode);
            fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({code:countryCode}),
              })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
     
    render() {     //Is an example
      return(
       <div></div>
      );
    }
}
```

My Problem: I can access the CountryCode on Server-Side with `req.body.code`, but i can't return the `/pages/de/index.js`.

Two Questions:

- Where is my mistake?
- Is it right to use the `ComponentdidMount()` function for this purpose, or should I better to create a custom `_app.js` for it? And if so, how can I do that?

I have little experience in Node.js environments. I would be very grateful if you could show me concrete solutions. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Your component doesn't have a `render()` method.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer My component has a `render()` method, I just didn't display it. To avoid confusion, I have adapted the code

Comment: In the `componentDidMount()`, you do a fetch of the root URL, passing the country code in the body of the HTTP POST. But you never seem to do anything with the Promise returned by `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your client side code located inside **pages/index.js** instead of **pages/de/index.js** this.
If you want to access the code from **pages/index.js** then define below code in **server.js**

```
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.code === 'DE') {
        return server.render(req, res, '/', req.query)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect the user to "/de/" using res.redirect('/de') in the server, or you can do it in the getInitialProps to make your logic in one place especially if you need to redirect on browser side also(using next/Router.push()).

Also if it is possible to put the key inside the cookies I think it is better to test the location before the page served, so the user does not see the redirection.